# passing variable into swf file embedded in wordpress via URL . HowTo?

Tags: actionscript-3, wordpress

I am having an swf file, embedded into wordpress. Now i need to pass values via URL. How can i achieve that. I actually want to get simpler solution rathar than going for a complex solution of SWFObject 2.0 .

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values via GET (`assets/file.swf?foo=bar`):

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  <param name="movie" value="assets/file.swf?foo=bar" />
  <param name="allowScriptAcess" value="sameDomain" />
</object>
```

Then retrieve them like this:

```
// In the root class:
trace(loaderInfo.parameters.foo); // bar
```